# Positive Definite Matrix And Transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If the matrix A is positive deﬁnite, so is the matrix A transpose . Why is this true?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Use the definition of positive definite and transpose. It's a jigsaw puzzle with only two pieces.

Comment: x transpose * A transpose * x >0 .... Can I say A transpose x is a vector then we x transpose * Nx1 vector which is a 1x1 which is a scalar greater than 0?

Comment: Positive definiteness is defined only for symmetric matrices.So the question is shaky. Or if you take the equivalent property (determinant of all principal submatrices be positive) you have to check this for $A^t$

Comment: bump...can someone tell me if my logic is right

Comment: First, you have to show that $A^T$ is Hermitian, because we may speak of the definiteness of a matrix only when it is Hermitian. Second, you need to check that $v^\ast A^Tv>0$ for every vector $v$ (that's what positive definiteness means for a Hermitian matrix), given that $u^\ast Au>0$ for every vector $u$.